# C++ Eigen AlignedBox Transformations

Tags: eigen

I am trying to make my first steps with the C++ Eigen library. The Matrix functionality was very intuitive but I have some problems using the AlignedBox type from the Geometry module.

For an exercise I have to rotate an AlignedBox around a specific point and be able to translate it within a 2D plane using Eigen::Transform.
I have tried around for quite a while.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    // create 1D AlignedBox
    Eigen::MatrixXf sd1(1,1);
    Eigen::MatrixXf sd2(1,1);
    sd1 << 0;
    sd2 << 3;
    Eigen::AlignedBox1f box1(sd1, sd2);

    // rotation of 45 deg
    typedef Eigen::Rotation2D<float> R2D;
    R2D r(M_PI/4.0);

    // create transformation matrix with rotation of 45 deg
    typedef Eigen::Transform< float, 2, Eigen::AffineCompact > SE2;
    SE2 t;
    t = r;

    // how to apply transformation t to box1???

    return 0;
}
```

I thought I have to multiply the AlignedBox with t.matrix() but since the Box is no matrix type and I did not find any useful build in function I have no idea how to apply the transformation. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that result will be a 2D box. You can compute it by applying the affine transformation to the two 2D extremities, and updating the 2D box with the `extend` method, e.g.:

```
AlignedBox2f box2;
box2.extend(t * Vector2f(box1.min()(0), 0));
box2.extend(t * Vector2f(box1.max()(0), 0));
```

To apply another transformation to `box2`, you can use the same principle on the 4 corners of the box that you can get using the `AlignedBox::corner` method.

Comment: Thanks, that helped already a lot. I think you meant "t * Vector2f(box1.min()(0), 0)" instead of SE2 * ... since SE2 is just the typedef